# virtualbox kernel service not running exiting

Tags: virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 as guest OS on Oracle VM on Windows 8.1. After some update the top menu and launcher disappeared. After restarting the VM I'am getting the message:

> virtualbox kernel service not running exiting

And Ubuntu comes up with a blank desktop and is not fully loaded.
How to solve this problem?Even  i am not able to open terminal .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)